# how to know a child window disappears(context menuor or tooltip etc) as soon as the parent window goes into background?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that sends instructions(click or find ) to windows that performs actions on the target windows application.But if the instruction is clicking on the file menu of a window which opens a context menu, the next instruction (select context menu item) should not fail if any other application come to foreground on the windows.

So before perfoming action, (checking isWindow is not accurate) need to find out the window still there? or

Is there something in the window properties that will tell me whether it stays or disappears as soon as other application gain focus?

Comment: Check the window handle is the foreground window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten That will tell me what window is on the foreground, but i don't know whether my window doesn't exist or is it in the background

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). The solution to *X* is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).